# How to use Google Mobile Ads SDK 21 in Android API Level smaller than 19?

Tags: android, admob, google-mobile-ads

I have users and showing ads from Android API Level 16. However, [Google Mobile Ads SDK 21 requires a minimum Android API level of 19.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration#migrate_to_sdk_v21) How can I target the users of API Level 18 or earlier?

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the latest AdMob SDK on devices below API `19`.
The minimum supported SDK by Admob `21.0.10` is now `19`.
You can either set your app to use `minSdkVersion 19` or use AdMob's older SDK version i.e `20.6.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I use both Admob versions? If so, how?

Comment: No, you cannot use both AdMob versions at the same time.

Comment: It is most likely that future updates will require API 19 or higher. Therefore, I have to lose users of API level 18 or earlier If I prioritize showing ads. NO ALTERNATIVES! :(

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a a way: [flavours](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#dependencies)

You'll have to manage and build two apps basically. One "old" version and a new one. The difference will only be the dependencies and the specific class, that uses this dependencie. You will create 2 versions of that class. the rest stays the same. In the end you wil have to compile two APK and ship two APKs.
Google Play store will accept both and hand out the "old" version to old phones and the "new" version to new phones.

This is a bit complex and time cosnuming and all depends if it's worth it for your specific use case. It works great and Android Studio let's you swap between the two code bases very easily.